# preserve index order when sorting column with duplicate numbers pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have an unordered pandas series `pd_series` that looks like this:

```
0        1
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        1
        ...
1003    99
1004    99
1005    99
1006    99
1007    99
```

(first column is the idx and second column contains the values I want to sort smallest to largest)

When I try to sort the values using `pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`:

```
pd_series.sort_values(axis=0,inplace=True, ascending=True)
```

The results that I am getting look like this:

```
0        1
7        1
6        1
5        1
8        1
       ...
138    112
139    112
140    112
141    112
142    112
```

As it can be seen, the index order is not preserved. For values of 1, instead of `0,7,6,5,8,...` it should be `0,1,2,3,4,5,...`. How can I sort duplicate numbers of a dataframe/pandas series while preserving the index order they had before sorting?

Comment: Cannot reproduce it, but how about playing around with the parameter `kind`? Try `kind = 'stable'` (or `'mergesort'`): https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: Neither of them work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! It seems to work properly for my particular case using `kind='stable'`.